# Supervisor - Can't start supervisorctl as root or user (User is set in config)

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, supervisord

I start supervisor as root:

`sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

Then I try to start up supervisorctl:

```
(myapp)appuser@ip-172-31-21-65:~/appuser$ supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

Supervisor starts with the following mesage:

```
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 224
```

Trying to run the second command as root is also unsuccessful. My understanding is that this is by design.

All the advice I find suggests that I should set my user as the user that executes the command, but this is already how I have it all configured:

Here is the script file that I am using:

```
NAME="myapp"                              
DJANGODIR=/home/appuser/myapp             
SOCKFILE=/home/appuser/myapp/gunicorn.sock        
USER=appuser                                        
GROUP=webdata                                     
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings             
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=myapp.wsgi
```

I'm not sure what is screwing it up? I think it might be the `GROUP` setting, as I don't recognize that value. But if I comment it out, it doesn't seem to make a difference. How should I troubleshoot this?

EDIT: I created a group named `supervisor`, added `appuser` to it and changed the `GROUP` setting to match, but still no joy.

This is my supervisord.conf:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/super$
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TE$

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

And my configuration file for the app:

```
[program:myapp]
command = /home/appuser/myapp/gunicorn_start.sh ; Command to start app
user = appuser ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /home/appuser/myapp/logs/supervisor.log ; Where to write$
redirect_stderr = true ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

My supervisor version is:

```
>supervisord --version
3.0b2
```

Comment: What version of supervisord are you using? And please provide the supervisor config not the gunicorn one.

Comment: I've updated the question with the requested info. Setting the user to www-data didn't help.

Comment: try chmod-socket = 664 in the configuration file for the app.

Comment: I pasted `chmod-socket = 664` into the app's configuration file, but I'm still getting the same permissions error.

Comment: From what I am understanding, supervisor is having trouble getting to a specific Python file. I noticed someone voted to close this question. If this isn't a Python issue but is a server issue or Linux issue, please guide me in the right direction and I will be on my way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I added my username to the superisord.conf file under the `[unix_http_server]` section like so:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
chown=appuser:supervisor        ;(username:group)
```

This seemed to work- time will tell if it continues working after I manage solve the rest of the supervisor issues.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for anyone coming across this: you need to give the group permissions to read/write to the socket too. So change chmod=0700 to chmod=0770

Answer (score 6):

Adding more to Adam's solution.

you need to give the group permissions to read/write to the socket too.

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0770                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
chown=appuser:supervisor        ;(username:group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the provided answers but the problem was not solved.
Finally, I used `;` to comment the following line, and the problem was solved.

```
; logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; main log file; default $CWD/supervisord.log
```

Comment: in [supervisord] section (where this row is: logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log)
put: user=YourUser (or uncomment it)